# from flutter then open android module in android studio but how to go back to flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, apk

In Android Studio, with the Flutter plugin, I open the Android module in order to create signed bundle/apk. How can I turn back to Flutter mode?

[How to open Android module in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkaHB.jpg)

I want to use only this project file and don't want try other of same project file yet seems I already generated keystore and everything on this one

Comment: Just open again your root folder where you have the "lib" folder. You can click the "open project" option and choose that root folder of the project and not the "Android" folder.

Comment: It does open my flutter dart now how do I go step a higher in hierarchy to see other files like android, assets, gradle etc, in tools menu I do not see flutter submenu, I wonder if this permanent